# How to select top (5) rows with specified Id and latest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

The table is this:

```
Id_P  Id_Utente   PasswordOld_                      DateOld_
1     134         E0476F2E85A84FB4E68AA26A841A86FA  8/01/2015 10:30:00 PM
2     134         9C454981DE1702C7AAD3B435B51404EE  8/02/2015 10:30:00 PM
3     134         BA0D9BE25565C34CAAD3B435B51404EE  8/03/2015 10:30:00 PM
4     134         9C6C9E34FB63DC9DE68AA26A841A86FA  8/04/2015 10:30:00 PM
5     134         14BEE187F918F8817584248B8D2C9F9E  8/04/2015 10:30:00 PM
6     135         9A70F4507624037CAAD3B435B51404EE  15/01/2015 10:30:00 PM
7     135         C3DB775AE3B3BD29E68AA26A841A86FA  15/02/2015 10:30:00 PM
8     135         0BB76B9CA33D8E31AAD3B435B51404EE  15/03/2015 10:30:00 PM
9     136         9A70F4507624037CAAD3B435B51404EE  26/01/2015 10:30:00 PM
10    136         C3DB775AE3B3BD29E68AA26A841A86FA  26/02/2015 10:30:00 PM
11    136         0BB76B9CA33D8E31AAD3B435B51404EE  26/03/2015 10:30:00 PM
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I need to retrieve the 5 PasswordOld_ with let's say Id_Utente = 134 and DateOld_ the latest.

Comment: Probably there can be some problem also due to the fact that the type of the DateOld_ field is a ntext and not a Datetime type...

Comment: Im using sql server, visual studio...

Comment: @Cris Id_P is an autoincrement column ,right? Is your DateOld_ column is not a user input?

Comment: yes it's only for more details.... probably useless (Id_P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `DateOld_` field is of type `ntext`, you cannot do an `order by` on that. To sort the results based on that column, you need to convert the values in to `datetime` format.

You can execute the following query to fetch 5 rows with id_utente = 134 and sorted in descending order as per the time:

```
select top 5 * from table1 
   where id_utente = 134 
   order by convert(datetime, convert(varchar, dateold_)) desc;
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/138a7f/4)

Comment: I'm satisfied of this answer. Thanks!!

Comment: If it worked for you, you can accept it as a correct one, so that it would be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can use limit or top. Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM yourTablename ORDER BY DateOld_ DESC, Id_P DESC;
```

**SELECT LIMIT is not supported in all SQL databases**. But you can use the query above for SQL Server or MSAccess and the below query for mysql specifically.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTablename ORDER BY DateOld_ DESC LIMIT 5;
```

For more info, you can visit [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).

Comment: `limit` is MySQL specific. OP is using sql-server, so it won't work.

Comment: As per the OP's comments, `DateOld_` is of type `ntext`. You cannot do an `order by` on this type of column.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `order by` clause

```
select top 5 * 
from table1 
where Id_P in (1,2,3,4,5)
order by DateOld_;
```

Comment: As per the OP's comments, `DateOld_` is of type `ntext`. You cannot do an `order by` on this type of column.

Comment: I still get the error: 

{"The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."}

after using the following query:

Dim QuerySelect2 As String = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TAB_PASSWORDS WHERE Id_Utente_ = '" & Id_CP & "' ORDER BY DataOld_"

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` is the best way.

Use it like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
LIMIT 5
```